# Characteristic cycle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Is there a good introduction to characteristic cycle of D modules(or constructive sheaves)? I just encountered this concept recently and I really would like to see some examples of calculations using characteristic cycles.

Answer (score 1):

Hotta, Takeuchi, and Tanasaki's "D-modules and representation theory" has a calculation of the characteristic cycle of an integrable connection.

You might also try computing examples with D being the nth Weyl algebra, in which case you can use Groebner basis theory. Macaulay2 has a package for these types of computations.